# Form validation on same page or different page?

Tags: php, forms

Consider these two simplified scenarios:

```
Script Name: script1.php

Validate form fields and if validated; redirect user to another page...

<form action=script1.php>
form fields.....
</form>
```

Second Scenario:

```
Script Name: script1.php

 <form action=script2.php>
 Form fields.....
 </form>

 Form fields are posted to script2.php and validated there and then the user is redirected to the next page...
```

Is the first method of form validation (within the same script) better than the second method (sending form data to an "intermediate page" for validation/DB input and then redirect) or second better than the first and why??

Comment: Neither.  Validate client-side.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation  There are nice polyfills for this.  (Obviously, this doesn't mean blindly trust user input.  But, at least this means that if you get garbage data, rather than trying to figure out what was wrong with it and returning a friendly error after wasting the users' time with a page reload, you can just throw an exception, let it bubble up as whatever error makes sense (could be a 500 Internal Server Error if nothing else) and move on.)

Comment: Simply relying on client-side validation is dangerous since the user can easily disable that. Server side validation in addition to client side is required....

Comment: Did you read the rest of my comment?  The point is, any friendly validation should be done client-side.  Any actual data integrity security requirements should be on the server.  Usually if your data models are set up correctly, this happens automatically.

Answer (score 0):

From a personal point of view, I find it cleaner to have separate files. This then allows me to later on extend the system and allow other services to submit requests for validation without being overly cluttered. (For things, such as an application later on).

If you want to have it submitting to itself, you can require the validation script, allowing the two scripts to be clean & separate.

```
Script Name: script1.php

require 'script2.php';
/* Script 2 performs all validations */

<form action=script1.php>
form fields.....
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Self-action script is not a problem. More important is to separate concerns. You'll get large `if` blocks of "spaghetti code" if your html renders in the same file.

If you include both form rendering and validation conditionally then interpreter won't be parsing code it doesn't need.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    include 'submit_form.php';
}

include 'display_form.html.php';
```

Both scripts will be loaded only if invalid form was sent (forms should be submitted with POST method). Of course valid form ends with `exit;` after redirect header.

This "front script" is small, but it could include more than just these two files. In structural code it usually loads some common functions, procedures or templates (headers/footers). You may add some page specific authentication and authorization logic here:

- user needs to be logged in? - if session says otherwise redirect (maybe with current url to go back),
- user needs to be an admin? - display error or "page not found" to keep it hidden (should do the same for not logged in users in this case),

Also either "display" and "submit" might be split into smaller actions that also depend on simple logic. For example form might be already filled with data, because you editing something that was saved (so it's almost like form was sent, but will be displayed not because of validation errors). This file may grow fast and it's better if it controlls data flow only and load scripts it needs.

In object oriented programming it would be responsibility of main application factory that uses similar logic to build required objects composition. It's usualy handled in a different way, but some working with framework developers would be suprised.